# Including one page with WordPress functions into another

Tags: functions

I have two php pages, one is the main page that will hold all of my content. The second page is a whole bunch of php (that I have written as well as included wordpress functions) and js functions.

Lets say the container php file is Container.php
The included file is IncludedFile.php

I am including IncludedFile.php into Container.php by using `include_once('IncludedFile.php');`

When the Included file gets called onto my container page none of the WordPress functions that I have included work.

For example, the first function on the IncludedFile.php gets the current user:

`$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`

The next line down pulls a meta field from the current user to display on the page, but it is returning null.

`echo $current_user->favorite_color;`

Is the reason the wordpress functions are not working is the way that I am including my file into the other? Or is it a larger problem all together?

---

**Edit**

I've since added my `require('IncludedFile.php');` into my functions.php file so that I can include that file onto every page of my site.

Sample Code:

**Functions.php Function**

```
function display_content_on_all_pages() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<div class="container-holder">';
            require('IncludedFile.php');
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'Your not logged in....';
    }       
}
add_action('wp_footer','display_content_on_all_pages');
```

**IncludedFile.php**

```
<?php
   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( $current_user->user_login == 'TestUser' ) {
    echo 'You are TestUser';
  } else {
    echo 'You are not TestUser';
  }
?>
```

Comment: How is `Container.php` included?

Comment: Container is essentialy my page, so it lies in the root as page-pagename.php

Comment: `Container.php` is a WordPress theme template? WordPress functions in that file work correctly?

Comment: Yea, everything inside of container.php run correctly. But not inside of includedfile.php. I have also attempted to include wp-load.php to no avail.

Comment: If that file is at the "root" how do you get the WordPress functions to work? Or by "root" do you mean the theme's root?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the theme root

Comment: Can you post enough code from each of the two files to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I have posted some code above